# PHP SimpleXML - Get all Child Attributes if Parent Attribute Equals Variable Value

Tags: php, xml

I have an XML file I need to parse that looks similar to the below:

```
<directory name="Addbriefs">
<file name="File1.pdf"/>
<file name="File2.pdf"/>
<file name="File3.pdf"/>
<file name="File4.pdf"/>
</directory>

<directory name="Addusefulinfo">
<file name="FileA.pdf"/>
<file name="FileB.pdf"/>
<file name="FileC.pdf"/>
<file name="FileD.pdf"/>
</directory>

<directory name="Newbriefs">
<file name="FileZ.pdf"/>
<file name="FileY.pdf"/>
<file name="FileX.pdf"/>
<file name="FileW.pdf"/>
</directory>
```

I'm using PHP and want to be able to return a string which contains all of the name attributes for all file elements, but only if the name attribute of the parent element (directory) matches a variable that I define elsewhere.

i.e. if $var = "Newbriefs", I want to return the below string...

```
FileZ.pdf FileY.pdf FileX.pdf FileW.pdf
```

I successfully use simplexml elsewhere in my PHP code on the same website, but so far only to return a string of all attributes of a specific element type, not based on what the parent element attribute is.
I've checked and I'm not sure simplexml has the capabilities to achieve this?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this fairly simply with SimpleXML's [`xpath`](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php) method:

```
$var = "Newbriefs";
$files = $sxml->xpath("directory[@name='$var']/file/@name");
```

This query filters the `<directory>` tags to those with *name="Newbriefs"*, and then return the *name* attribute from all child `<file>` elements.

You can treat each element in the `$files` array as you would a normal `SimpleXMLElement` object - just cast it to string to get the contents:

```
$filename = (string) $files[0]; // FileZ.pdf
```

See https://eval.in/877375

Comment: Brilliant, just tested this and managed to get it working straight away. Thanks very much for your prompt assistance, it's very much appreciated!